# Displaying all the readmissions within 30days in sql

Tags: sql-server

i want to display all the admissions of patients that happened within 30 days

Here is how i have the data in the admission table:

```
patient_id   admid       adm_date                   dis_date
215          12          2011-05-17 14:43:00.000    2011-05-19 13:50:00.000
421          13          2009-05-12 05:51:00.000    2009-05-13 18:35:00.000
417          15          2014-02-12 16:44:00.000    2014-02-17 14:35:00.000
417          17          2015-04-04 19:54:00.000    2015-04-05 15:00:00.000
865          18          2009-09-28 05:40:00.000    2009-09-29 10:00:00.000
992          19          2010-05-20 05:06:00.000    2010-05-25 17:51:00.000
421          20          2009-05-29 07:15:00.000    2009-05-31 13:45:00.000
421          17          2009-06-18 04:52:00.000    2009-06-19 10:55:00.000
421          18          2009-06-30 13:39:00.000    2009-07-23 17:57:00.000
326          21          2010-07-01 17:41:00.000    2010-07-01 17:41:00.000
326          14          2010-06-07 11:35:00.000    2010-06-08 15:58:00.000
215          16          2011-06-02 14:40:00.000    2011-06-03 13:25:00.000
```

i tried this query:

```
With adm as 
(select patient_id, admid, adm_date, dis_date,row_number() over(partition by  patient_id order by adm_date) as r
from admissions) 
select a1.patient_id, a1.admid, a2.admid, a1.adm_date, a1.dis_date 
from adm a1 inner join adm a2 on a1.patient_id=a2.patient_id 
where a1.admid <> a2.admid and a1.r+1=a2.r
and a2.adm_date between a1.dis_date and dateadd(d,30, a1.dis_date)
order by a1.patient_id
```

I am getting the results as:

```
patient_id   admid       adm_date                    dis_date
215          12          2011-05-17 14:43:00.000     2011-05-19 13:50:00.000
421          13          2009-05-12 05:51:00.000     2009-05-13 18:35:00.000
421          20          2009-05-29 07:15:00.000     2009-05-31 13:45:00.000
421          17          2009-06-18 04:52:00.000     2009-06-19 10:55:00.000
326          14          2010-06-07 11:35:00.000     2010-06-08 15:58:00.000
```

but this is not the result i want because for patient 215 there are two admissions whose interval is less than 30 and i wanted to display both the admissions for this patient, but my result has only one admission.

i want the results to be displayed as below and not as the above:

```
patient_id   admid       adm_date                    dis_date
215          12          2011-05-17 14:43:00.000     2011-05-19 13:50:00.000
215          16          2011-06-02 14:40:00.000     2011-06-03 13:25:00.000
421          13          2009-05-12 05:51:00.000     2009-05-13 18:35:00.000
421          20          2009-05-29 07:15:00.000     2009-05-31 13:45:00.000
421          17          2009-06-18 04:52:00.000     2009-06-19 10:55:00.000
421          18          2009-06-30 13:39:00.000     2009-07-23 17:57:00.000
326          14          2010-06-07 11:35:00.000     2010-06-08 15:58:00.000
326          21          2010-07-01 17:41:00.000     2010-07-01 17:41:00.000
```

please help!

Comment: You will get better results if you format your post. It's very difficult to read your data.

Comment: I've just submitted an edit, it should fix the formatting when it's improved.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope someone else has a better solution than this. But it's my first pass. The CTEs find all first admissions where there is a "next" admission within 30 days. I use the row_number() to make sure that the "next" admission is the next row_number. So anything that has a "next", we know the row_number will be current row + 1. The union CTE makes sure the row_number values are distinct, and uses them to select from the original CTE. 
Like I said - I'd love to see the better answer to this.

```
;with cte
as (
    select patient_id
         , adm_date
         , dis_date
         , admid
         , row_number() over (order by patient_id, adm_date) 'r'
      from admissions
   )
, cte2
as (
       select adm1.r
            , adm1.r+1 'nextR'
         from cte adm1
    left join cte adm2
           on adm2.patient_id = adm1.patient_id
          and adm2.r = adm1.r+1
        where datediff(day,adm1.dis_date,adm2.adm_date) < 30
   )
, CompleteSet
as (
    select r
      from cte2
    union
    select nextR
      from cte2
   )
select cte.Patient_id
     , cte.admid
     , cte.adm_date
     , cte.dis_date
  from CompleteSet
  join cte
    on cte.r = CompleteSet.r
```

Comment: The below query worked:

With adm as 
(select patient_id, admid, adm_date, dis_date from admissions) 
select a1.patient_id, a1.admid, a2.admid, a1.adm_date, a1.dis_date 
from adm a1 inner join adm a2 on a1.patient_id=a2.patient_id 
where a1.admid <> a2.admid 
(ABS(DATEDIFF(d, a1.adm_date,a2.dis_date)) <= 30 OR ABS(DATEDIFF(d, a2.adm_date,a1.dis_date)) <= 30)
order by a1.patient_id, a1.adm_date

Thank you so much for your time!